# Why is componentDidUpdate only firing once after a series of updates to state? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am coding a scientific calculator, and am working on being able to click on the answer to a previous calculation (displayed is the 'history' section of the UI) and paste that answer into the display, as if the user had entered each of the digits of that answer one-by-one. So, if the user's previous calculation was 200 + 5, the "previous calculation" would be '200+5' and the 'previous answer' would be '205'. I want the user to be able to click the '205' and have that appear on the calculator as if they had typed in and 2 and then a 0 and then a 5. I want to treat each number as a separate input so that they can delete the numbers one at a time instead of just pasting the entire number as a single input.

The way I am trying to accomplish this is by splitting the previous calculation, held in an object held in state, into an array and looping through each number of that array and calling my addToDisplay function on it. The addToDisplay function updates the display, but, more importantly, triggers the condition that allows my componentDidUpdate function to run, which saves the current display information in an array in state called 'inputHistory.' I would expect, therefore, when I click '205' to see inputHistory has three items in it: ['2'], ['2', '0'], and ['2', '0', '5'].

This works when I input the three numbers individually, but when I do it from the previous calculation inputHistory only contains one item in it: ['2', '0', '5']. I asked a question recently about destructuring, and I thought maybe that is what is going on, but I don't see why, if that were the problem, I would get the correct results when I input the numbers one at a time. I think componentDidUpdate() is not firing with each call of addToDisplay() for some reason. I have also been very careful with managing asynchronous updates to state, but maybe something is falling through the cracks here.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 addToDisplay(input, parensNeeded, spanNeeded, exp) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let calcArr = prevState.newCalc ? [] : [...prevState.currentMath], finalInput
        // deal with any changes in exponent
        if (prevState.lastInput=== `<span class='invisible'>^</span><span class='exp-${this.state.exponentCount}'>□`) {
            calcArr.pop(); 
            finalInput = `<span class='invisible'>^</span><span class='exp-${this.state.exponentCount}'>${input}`
        } else {
            finalInput = input
        }
      //handle a minus becoming a negative sign 
        if (prevState.lastInput === ' - ' && /[&times;\-÷\+]/.test(prevState.currentMath[prevState.currentMath.length-2])) {
            calcArr[calcArr.length-1] = ' -'

        }
        //add the new input to the array
        calcArr.push(finalInput)
        //add/update spans to keep stylings intact
        let counter = prevState.exponentCount; 
        let spans = ''; 
        while (counter > 0) {
            spans = spans + '</span>';
            counter--;
            }; 
        //add new parens, if needed
        let styledParens = `<span class='parens exp-${this.state.exponentCount}'>)</span>`; 

        return { 
            currentMath : calcArr,
            calcActive : true,
            lastInput : input,
            inverse : false, 
            newCalc : false, 
            exponentCount : exp === '+' 
                ? prevState.exponentCount + 1
                : exp === '-'
                ? prevState.exponentCount - 1
                : prevState.exponentCount,
            spanStr : spanNeeded === 'yes' ? spans : prevState.spanStr,
            rightParensArr : parensNeeded === 'yes' 
                ? [styledParens, ...prevState.rightParensArr]
                : input === ')' | input === '</span>)'
                ? prevState.rightParensArr.length > 1
                ? prevState.rightParensArr.slice(1)
                : []
                : [...prevState.rightParensArr],
            inputHistUpdated : false 
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the goToAns() function, which adds whatever answer the user clicks on from the history to the display.

```
goToAns(e, answer) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    this.setState({
        rightParensArr : [],
        calActive: true,
        currentMath : [],
        spanStr : [],
        exponentCount : 0,
        lastInput : '',
        historyVisible : false,
        newCalc : false, 
        inputHistory : []
    }, () => {
        let ansArr = answer.split(''); 
        let i = 0;
        while (i < ansArr.length) {
            this.addToDisplay(ansArr[i]);
            i++; 
        } 
    }) 
}
```

And here is the function in componentDidUpdate(), which only fires after the addToDisplay() function runs.

```
if (!this.state.inputHistUpdated) {
        let newInputHist = {
            currentMath : [...this.state.currentMath], 
            exponentCount : this.state.exponentCount, 
            spanStr : this.state.spanStr, 
            lastInput : this.state.lastInput,
            rightParensArr : [...this.state.rightParensArr], 
        }

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                inputHistory : [newInputHist, ...prevState.inputHistory],
                inputHistUpdated : true
            }
        })

    }
```

Anyways, if anybody can see something I'm missing please feel free to point it out. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to have to point out https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly, and the fact that you're using setState in a very weird way. Compute what the next state should be, then set it. If you even remotely can, don't do what you're doing. Do all that calculation _before_ you call setState, and only pass setState the _state update_ that you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I cleaned up the code based on what you and the docs said, but that still has not fixed my problem. Is the fact that this is all wrapped in an event messing everything up?

Comment: Your post still shows code that computes a new state _inside_ `setState` instead of computing it first, then calling `this.setState(newState)`. Also note that you're setting state in `goToAns` and then you setting state _again_ in the call back function: that's a setState too many. Do your work first, and then as final step, update the component state so it can rerender itself. Don't use intermediate state setting: intermediary results are, by definition, not real state. And finally: if you're using `setState` based on the previous state in `componentDidUpdate`, things went wrong.

Comment: By all means update state based on changed _props_, but never update state _based on state_ in the function that gets triggered _by_ a change in state. That's just doing React wrong, and it's highly worth retaking the React tutorial (even if you already did) to (re)familiarise yourself with how you should be writing code, and thinking about data and updates, in React.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. I will definitely go back to basics and refresh my understanding. Thanks for all the help! I appreciate the time.